# Checkbox return false instead true in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-click

In below code `$scope.checkboxModel` set to false. When I click on checkbox and debug code on first click, it return false instead of true when checkbox is checked.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showPassword = '';
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.checkboxModel = false;
  $scope.showHidePassword = function(checkboxModel) {
    $scope.showPassword = checkboxModel ? '' : $scope.password;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
    <input type="password" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Show me Password <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel" ng-click="showHidePassword(checkboxModel)" /></span>
    <input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="showPassword" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why it is not returning true for first time when checkbox is checked?

Comment: Since clicking it will toggle the value, you would be better served using ng-change instead of ng-click on this one to get the value right in that event handler.

Comment: it is because you are calling showHidePassword method only on clicking on the checkbox. put a watch on password, and call this method. then it will work as you type in the password field

Comment: @CodingNinja I don't want to use watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happend because of version mismatch. see the example below that use angular 1.3.14

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showPassword = '';
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.checkboxModel = false;
  $scope.showHidePassword = function(checkboxModel) {
    $scope.showPassword = checkboxModel ? $scope.password : '';
    console.log("checkboxModel : " + checkboxModel);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
    <input type="password" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Show me Password <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel" ng-click="showHidePassword(checkboxModel)" /></span>
    <input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="showPassword" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
</div>
```